# Detecting application start up with python

Tags: python, python-3.x, windows, psutil

I've working on a windows python program and I need it to run once I open an app. Is it possible ? If so how would I implement it ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We need some information, what did you want to do?
Did you wanna know, if a process is started and then you will continue you python script? Than you can do this:

```py
import psutil

def is_process_running(processName):
    for process in psutil.process_iter(): # iterates through all processes from your OS
        try: 
            if processName.lower() in process.name().lower(): # lowers the name, because "programm" != proGramm"
                return True # if the process is found, then return true
        except (psutil.NoSuchProcess, psutil.AccessDenied, psutil.ZombieProcess): # some failures what could go wrong
            pass
    return False;

while(!is_process_running('nameOfTheProcess') # only continue as long as the return is False
    time.sleep(10) # wait 10 seconds
```

For further information:
[psutil-docs](https://psutil.readthedocs.io/en/latest/)

Comment: could you specify how this code works so I can better incorporate it into my script

Comment: I comment the code. Could you read it now?

Comment: yes it's much easier to understand now

Comment: Thanks. Is there a way to accomplish the same functionality but asynchronously?
(i.e. I mean instead of the polling approach you suggested above via time.sleep(..)?

Comment: @RidaShamasneh No problem. However, on Stack Overflow, it's customary to upvote as a form of thanks instead of saying it directly. Could you clarify what you mean by 'same but asynchronously'? What exactly are you looking to achieve?"

Answer (score 1):

This can be achieved in multiple ways, following can also be the one.

```
import subprocess 
#sub-process library being part of python doesn't
#require any additional installation and can do all the work.


#For Windows operating system we can use 'tasklist'
#in place of 'ps aux' as the first argument
#(haven't work with windows lately but this is close to something i remember).
#check_output api called when shell=true,returns list of running processes.

running_processes = subprocess.check_output(['ps aux'], shell=True)

#check if the application needed is running, for brevity, I am using firefox,
#if yes, it fires off another python script.

if bytes('firefox',encoding='utf-8') in running_processes:
    subprocess.call(['python3', '/path/to/application.py'])
else:
    print('it not')
```